Is strict subtyping supported in TypeScript?
I need to define a type in TypeScript that expresses "any subtype of T, but not T", where T is the formal type parameter of a generic type. Let me give a couple of use cases to motivate this need.
Use Case 1
type AnySubtypeOf<T> = ? // the strict subtype expression I am looking for

class FamilyTree<T> {
    parent: T;
    children: AnySubtypeOf<T>[];

    constructor(familyTree: FamilyTree<T>) {
        this.parent = familyTree.parent;
        this.children = familyTree.children;
    }
}

The semantics of FamilyTree disallow any child to be of a type of its parent. That's why I need to constraint the types of the objects that can be pushed to the children array to be any subtype of T but not T (i.e., strict subtype of T).
My goal is to improve development experience in the creation of instances of FamilyTree type. Say we have the following classes:
class A { 
  x: number; 
  constructor(x: number) { this.x = x; } 
}

class B extends A { 
  y: number; 
  constructor(x: number, y: number) { super(x); this.y = y; } 
}

class C { 
  x: number;
  z: number; 
  constructor(x: number, z: number) { this.x = x; this.z = z; } 
}

class D { 
  w: string; 
  constructor(w: string) { this.w = w; } 
}

Here are the expected compilation results for several instantiations of FamilyTree:
const a = new A(1);
const b = new B(2, 3);
const c = new C(4, 5);
const d = new D("Hey!");

new FamilyTree<A>({ parent: a, children: [ b, c ] }); // ✅ No TS error
new FamilyTree<A>({ parent: a, children: [ b, d ] }); // ❌ TS error since d is not a subclass of A
new FamilyTree<A>({ parent: a, children: [ b, a ] }); // ❌ TS error since a is not an strict subclass of A

Use Case 2
Here is an example of the issue I am facing in the context of Monguito, a lightweight polymorphic abstract repository that enables easy and fast definition of custom repositories for Node.js apps. Monguito is built on top of Mongoose, but both Mongoose and Node.js are implementation details for the purpose of this post.
What really matters is that the developer of any custom repository must specify some data about the domain model handled by their repository. This data consists of the type and schema of every object that composes the model. Here is an example of a book model:
class Book {
    readonly id?: string;
    readonly title: string;
    readonly isbn: string;

    constructor(book: Book) {
        this.id = book.id;
        this.title = book.title;
        this.isbn = book.isbn;
    }
}

class PaperBook extends Book {
    readonly edition: number;
    
    constructor(paperBook: PaperBookType) {
        super(paperBook);
        this.edition = paperBook.edition;
    }
}

class AudioBook extends Book {
    readonly hostingPlatforms: string[];

    constructor(audioBook: AudioBookType) {
        super(audioBook);
        this.hostingPlatforms = audioBook.hostingPlatforms;
    }
}

And here is the definition for MongooseBookRepository, the custom repository that performs database operations on objects composing the book model:
class MongooseBookRepository
    extends MongooseRepository<Book>
    implements BookRepository {

    constructor() {
        super({
            type: Book,
            schema: BookSchema,
            subtypes: [
                { type: PaperBook, schema: PaperBookSchema },
                { type: AudioBook, schema: AudioBookSchema },
            ],
        });
    }
}

As you can see, the hierarchy of the book model defines a root object Book and two subtypes (leaves) i.e., PaperBook and AudioBook. The semantics of the book model need to be strict enough to disallow the declaration of the root object Book or any object unrelated to Book as a subtype, as they may cause runtime execution errors, specially if Book is declared abstract (but it could also be a concrete, instantiable type). Furthermore, in the context of the book model, Book cannot be both the root and also a leaf of the book model, as you may agree.
Here is where the thing gets tricky. MongooseRepository is Monguito's main asset. This is the abstract repository that includes a set of boilerplate CRUD operations that any custom repository must inherit from to benefit from it. All considered, here is a simplified snapshot of MongooseRepository (you may find its complete definition here):
abstract class MongooseRepository<T>
    implements Repository<T> {
    private readonly domainTree: DomainTree<T>;

    protected constructor(
        domainModel: DomainModel<T>,
        protected readonly connection?: Connection) {
        this.domainTree = new DomainTree(domainModel);
    }
}

The only missing pieces in all this puzzle are DomainModel and DomainTree. The former is encoded as a TS interface and the latter is an implementation class for such an interface (irrelevant for this use case, but you can see its implementation here). Here is the definition I require for DomainModel:
type AnySubtypeOf<T> = ? // the strict subtype expression I am looking for

interface DomainModel<T> {
    type: T;
    schema: Schema<T>;
    subtypes?: DomainModel<AnySubtypeOf<T>>[];
}

I have also simplified the original definition of DomainModel for illustrative purposes. Schema is a Mongoose type irrelevant for this use case too. What matters is that the formal type parameter of DomainModel in subtypes must express "any strict subtype of T" to comply with the aforementioned Monguito's semantics. Moreover, the generic nature of MongooseRepository, designed to enable the implementation of any kind of custom repository, disallows the use of any auxiliary formal type parameter in DomainModel.

I understand that TypeScript does not explicitly support existential quantification, making it difficult to come up with a solution to my problem.
Furthermore, the type system of TypeScript is (only) based on structural subtyping for a good reason: flexibility. This means that any JS object that includes the same properties as another that is meant to be the root on a type hierarchy is, in fact, semantically equal, despite they may have different names. Just like the (unnamed) object { x: number } is semantically equal to class A in my first use case. That's why structural subtyping is also known as static duck-typing (remember the sentence "if it walks like a duck and it quacks like a duck, then it must be a duck").
I'm not an expert on Type Theory, but I believe that enforcing strict subtyping in a nominal type system-based language is easier (or should I even say possible?).
All considered, it then seems to me that I won't be able to enforce strict subtyping in my use cases. However, if that's the case, can anyone confirm my suspicion and reasoning, or else explain to me how to express strict subtyping in any of my use cases?
Many thanks! 

"Moreover, I need to ensure strict subtyping, meaning that instances of type T are not to be allowed." Please [edit] to motivate this. What actually goes wrong when you allow "instances of type T", keeping in mind that structural subtyping means that every instance of type S extends T is also an instance of T? The very nature of that seems to fight against the type system, and rather than try to force TS into submission, I'd rather understand the use case. This feels like an XY problem without more information.

When you [edit], please also make this a [mre] so that you define A, B, C, and D for us, and fix any typos in your code. It's hard to tell from this question whether or not you actually understand structural typing and how it differs from nominal typing. The idea of a "standalone class" doesn't make much sense in TypeScript. I can write class X { a = 1 } class Y { a = 1; b = 2 } and Y extends X is true despite Y being "standalone". So, we'll need a substantial [edit] here to clear this stuff up, I think.

As currently proposed, it does not sounds like it's possible because TypeScript uses structural typing as opposed to nominal meaning that if your class D were to have the same properties as B it would still pass. Personally I cannot think of a valid use case for what you're trying to do. Is it really better having children be of type (B | C)[] rather than A[]? Moreover, if you don't want instances of A, what about making it an abstract class then?

Thanks for editing, but still, what actually goes wrong if you allow new Parent<A>({ content: a, children: [ b, a ] });? Why would it matter? Your [mre] needs to show an actual problem, otherwise the only answer you'll get is "this isn't possible and you shouldn't try to do it". As said above, you could make A abstract, but that doesn't affect Parent.

Awesome comments, thanks @jcalz and @moonstar-x! I intended to provide a minimal, complete, reproducible, but yet simpler illustration of an issue I'm facing at Monguito. Anyhow, the goal is to improve DevEx and display TS compiling errors in the aforementioned Parent instantiation scenarios; by definition, Parent cannot know which strict subtypes of T can children hold. If that's not possible given the semantics of TS, please let me know, it'd be just fine to me :)

Sorry, I don't get it. TS's type system doesn't make it easy to represent "strict" subtypes, and I still haven't seen a [mre] where it matters. Could you [edit] to show a use case where it matters that Parent<A> accepts an instance of A? Why must it be a subclass? What, specifically, goes wrong? All I hear from the comments here are that you want it to error, not why.

Apologies @jcalz, I am honestly struggling here, mate. As I said, I did not want to bring the entire use case I am working on since this post would otherwise have been kilometric. Anyways, since you seem motivated (thanks for that! :), you may see a real use case here. In any case, I always thought of StackOverflow as an appropriate platform to ask theoretical questions on programming languages; I've appreciated many of them myself :D.

Hmm, I'm not asking for an "entire" use case, just one that motivates your question. Mongoose/nestjs mean little to me so I'm not sure what I can gain from that link. If you can't [edit] the above code to demonstrate why it would be bad to allow an instance of A in there then I don't know what to say. The answer "you can't do this and I don't know why you care" isn't something I want to spend time writing. If I could see something actually go wrong, maybe I could say "oh, this is how you do it" because I understand the use case. But I think we've gone back and forth enough so ‍♂️

Morning @jcalz. Many thanks for the amount of time you have already spent in my issue, and apologies if you have felt stubbornness from my side; my brain was so fried yesterday that I could not genuinely think of a succinct way to express the actual use case I am working on. Now that I feel fresh, I believe I've managed to do it :D. I wrote it at the bottom of the post. Hope is not too late for a last review from your side, I very much appreciate your expertise on TS and willingness to help me :). Please do not hesitate to let me know any doubt/concern/disagreement on the new use case. Thanks!

The fact that you need the subtypes to be constructible while the parent is allowed to be abstract is something you can model. See this playground link. But it still seems you don't care about subtypes the way you claim; all you say is "it doesn't make sense", which I just don't see, sorry. See the bottom section of the playground where I show that you can have an abstract parent class and a concrete subclass whose instance types are identical to each other; unless you want to prohibit such a concrete subclass, then what you're asking for isn't actually what you want.

(see prev comment.) So how should we proceed? I've yet to see a use case that warrants what you're claiming to want, and your underlying use case seems to just want a distinction between abstract and concrete constructors, which has very little to do with the question as asked. This is looking more and more like an XY problem. Maybe you could [edit] to ask about your actual use case, make it a [mre] suitable for working on in an IDE (so declare everything you're using) and don't make the subject about "strict subtyping"? Or you can leave it as-is and I'll disengage; either way is fine with me.

All due respect, I think that you are not understanding the issue at hand. It is not about modelling a TS class hierarchy with an abstract root type and concrete leaves types; it's simply about prohibiting the spec of a class hierarchy where the root type is also included as a leaf. Why? Because those are the semantics of Monguito; badly specified domain models will make Monguito to fail, as I said. While I've done my best, you insist on that you miss an "actual use case". Well, I also believe this is a sign that we should stop this conversation here ‍♂️. Thanks for your time anyways.

I'm with moonstar-x, this seems like you don't understand structural vs nominal typing. And I'm with jcalz that this is almost certainly an xy problem and there's a better way to model the constraints you are trying to express. I appreciate the level of effort you've put into this and your willingness to engage, but when the experts are telling you your approach doesn't make sense it's usually a good idea to take a step back and rethink your entire approach.

Thanks Jared. I am very much opened to learn from experts. However, if it's a XY problem, maybe directional questions like "what do you mean by...?" instead of "I don't get what you mean" would help (if I was an expert I wouldn't have raised my question, right?). Anyhow, the bright side of all these conversations is that apparently reasoning about strict subtyping in a structural typed language such as TS makes no sense or is impossible (does that sound as a reasonable answer to my original question, BTW?); either way, I'm fine with that and appreciate the efforts of the three of you :)

@JosuMartinez "reasoning about strict subtyping in a structural typed language such as TS makes no sense or is impossible" that is an extremely sweeping statement that is untrue. It would probably be much more fair to say that "modeling this specific problem in this specific way is not a good fit for a structurally typed language". If you have a language in mind where it is possible to express this constraint in the type system it would probably be a good idea to include an example of it, but the answer to your question as asked is probably still "you can't do it that way in Typescript".

Hey Jared, you may want to see the solution I've just suggested for my first use case. It works like a charm for class hierarchies!

The short answer to my question is that strict subtyping is not natively supported in TypeScript and that the type definition flexibility offered by the language's type system (i.e., structural typing) hinders trivial workarounds to further constraint subtyping.
If we are to flip over our minds into nominative type systems, however, there is a workaround that could help us, with some extra effort, to partially achieve strict subtyping. The idea is to introduce branding (also known as type-tagging).
We can add some extra information to our types to differentiate them in a pseudo-nominal way. To do so, we define a generic Brand<T, S> type as follows:
type Brand<T, S> = T & { __brand: S };

Brand is an intersection of a base type T and a brand type { __brand: S }. This makes the resulting branded type unique from its base type. Furthermore, branded types can be used anywhere an object of type T is expected.
We can now use Brand to enable the definition of strict subtypes of T. Also bear in mind that some extra type assertions are required. Here is an alternative piece of working code for use case 1:
type Child<T> = Brand<T, 'Child'>; // represents any subtype of T

class FamilyTree<T> {
  parent: T;
  children: Child<T>[];

  constructor(familyTree: FamilyTree<T>) {
    this.parent = familyTree.parent;
    this.children = familyTree.children;
  }
}

// The definition of classes A-D remain the same

const a = new A(1);
const b = new B(2, 3) as Child<B>;
const c = new C(4, 5) as Child<C>;
const d = new D('Hey!') as Child<D>;

new FamilyTree<A>({ parent: a, children: [b, c] }); // ✅ No TS error
new FamilyTree<A>({ parent: a, children: [b, d] }); // ❌ TS error since d is not a subclass of A
new FamilyTree<A>({ parent: a, children: [b, a] }); // ❌ TS error since a is not an strict subclass of A

Unfortunately, I cannot use this technique to achieve strict subtyping in my second use case since I cannot expect (and don't want to, anyway) Monguito developers to manually write type assertions (i.e., as Child<X>) when specifying their domain model. So, I understand that nothing can be done to improve developer experience in this area. Please prove me wrong! 
As a final note, check the bottom of this awesome article to know more about TS branding. Also, you can see how branding is also used in the code base of TS itself here.
